# Powershell - Using ConvertTo-HTML and need to add CSS based on a fields content

Tags: html, css, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell's (v2) `ConvertTo-HTML` function to convert a SQL query to a table that I then include in an email.
On a basic level it works fine, but I now want to add some CSS to colour a field if that field is greater than 0.

My SQL is:

```
$SQL1 = "SELECT DATE, LS, TCO, FCO FROM test.table1 
        WHERE DATE = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        ORDER BY LS"
```

Example Data is:

```
'2015-09-29', 'aaa', 150, 10
'2015-09-29', 'bbb', 267, 0
```

My Powershell is:

```
$table1 = $result1 | `
ConvertTo-Html `
    -property DATE, `
        LSR, `
        TCO, `
        FCO `
    -Fragment

 $htmlbody = @"
    <html>
    <head><title>HTML TABLE</title></head>
    <body>
        <style> [CSS GOES HERE] </style>
        . . .
        $table1
    </body>
    </html>
"@
```

But I need to be able to add css to the last field on the table so if the field is `> 0` I add a class to turn it red.
I'm assuming I need some kind of `IF` statement somewhere

```
IF [field] > 0 THEN [ADD CLASS]
```

But can't see where to put it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From What I have been able to deduce, it is not possible to add CSS to individual elements using `ConvertTo-Html`.

I did however find a function called called `ConvertTo-ADVHtml` which does allow this.[See Here](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/2448-create-advanced-html-tables-in-powershell-convertto-advhtml)

Comment: You can consider html parser like https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex